# PHP How to convert a controller url call to a function

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to integrate two pieces of code together. The existing code already generates a hash code and the function is called with this URL

```
 header(Location:  http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/subfolder/controller.php?document&validate&patient_id=".$pid."&document_id=".$nid."&process=true");
```

Is there another way to execute this function without doing a header redirect because the header redirect is causing the code to halt processing upon redirect.

In the controller file there is only one line echo Controller::act($_GET);

I tried to convert it to a function. I tried.

```
   include_once controller.php  //class file

  function hash_tag($pid, $nid){

           $filetag = "document&validate&patient_id=".$pid."&document_id=".$nid."&process=true";

      echo Controller::act($filetag);


 }

 hashtag($pid, $nid);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Code for the Controller.class.php file can be seen here 
https://github.com/juggernautsei/Drag-N-Drop/blob/master/library/classes/Controller.class.php

Comment: `Controller::act` is custom class? Or an framework open-source?

Comment: OpenSource custom class. It seams to be a custom class because I can't find it referenced anywhere.

Comment: wow, answered only today LOL, apparently you've got the solution, I wish you luck in your project!

Comment: Well, I checked my calendar and the 21st was Friday. Monday was the 24th which turned into a very busy day on another project. So, today is the first time I saw your comment. Still working on a solution. The check mark below was because it made me think to pass the variables in a session instead of the URL. That is why I marked it as a solution. But it is not a complete solution. It just gets me to the next hump in the road.

Comment: Now I have a solution. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass the string from the GET request to the controller.
But Contract::act() works on an array ($_GET is a superglobal array).

Build an array inside the function and assign the parameters of the function to it, then pass it to the controller, like so:

```
include_once 'controller.php';

function hash_tag($pid, $nid)
{
    $array = array();

    $array['document'] = 1;
    $array['validate'] = 1;
    $array['patient_id'] = $pid:
    $array['document_id'] = $nid;
    $array['process'] = 1;

    echo Controller::act($array);
} 

hashtag($pid, $nid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your code inside `controller.php` but considering that your first approach was accessing that code via url parameters, I'll assume that you are executing variables in that code as `GET` variables (example: `$_GET['patient_id']`).

If that is the case, now that you are executing that code via `include_once` you have to change the way you set your variables in `controller.php` because there is not more `$_GET`.

Comment: You both are close. I added a line of code to spit out the $_GET array and Jens-André Koch is right I have to build the array which I did but now passing the array to the controller is the challenge. The echo Controller::act($array); does not call the controller.

Comment: I don't know what you have inside controller.php which is the reason what I'm not include a new way of passing variables in my answer.

Comment: Add the code located on controller.php to your question. That way it will be easier to see how you have to implement that code. If you are affraid that the code is too many lines, just post some lines at the beggining and at the end.

Comment: Here is where the controller code can be seen. https://github.com/juggernautsei/Drag-N-Drop/blob/master/controller.php

Comment: The code inside this page: Controller.class.php is the one it should be posted.

Comment: Here is the link to the Controller.class.php file. https://github.com/juggernautsei/Drag-N-Drop/blob/master/library/classes/Controller.class.php

Comment: Given `echo Controller::act($array);` is executed, then what is the output? Which error occurs?

Comment: The class in Controller.class.php is using directly the superglobal $_GET and even $_POST

Comment: In other words: it's a real mess. $qarray contains routing information for class and action/ method name resolution and also the method parameters. The method act() is basically a router. Anyway.. where is the documentation for this thingy.